# How to apply waitForExist() on two selector simultaneously in webDriverIO

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

Currently, I am upgrading the WebDriverIo version from 4 to 5 wherein one of the existing tests we are applying waitForExist on two selectors simultaneously. In v4 it's like this `.waitForExist(selector + loadingSelector, null, true)` But in V5 waitForExist chaining to selector and therefore I've refactored this to `await (sel1+loadingSelector).waitForExist(0,true,null);` but this throwing error `TypeError: (selector + loadingSelector).waitForExist is not a function

Here is my bit of command code:

```
addIdeCommand('ideOpenFolder', async function (folder, treeCls, fuzzy) {
    var sel1 =await browser.$(sel1);
    var loadSelector = await browser.$(sel2);
    

        await sel1.waitForDisplayed();
        // Wait for the loading icon to disappear (true = not exists)
       **await (selector+loadSelector).waitForExist(0,true,null);**
        await this.waitUntil(async function () {
            //something
        });
});
```

Can someone please help me with how to apply waitForExisting() on multiple selectors at the same time?

Comment: `selector` variable is not defined. did you mean `sel1` instead?

Comment: Yes, it should be sel1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Promise.all:

```
await Promise.all([
  method1,
  method2,
  ...
])
```